# Vue and Vue Resource

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I'm trying to send a post request via vue-resource and I can't quite seem to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly.

I'm using Laravel 5.1 to process the request.

The following jquery code works fine from within my Vue method.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/purchase/save-cart-items',
        data: { 'purchaseItems' : purchaseItems},
        success: function (response) {
            if(response == "ok") {
                alert("Cart saved successfully.");   
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem saving this cart. Please try again.');
            }
        }
    });
```

However, the replacing the jquery above with the following vue-resource post request doesn't work for some reason.  I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.  Vue-resource is properly included in the project as I'm using it for get requests without issue.

```
this.$http.post('/purchase/save-cart-items', {purchaseItems:purchaseItems}, function (data, status, request) {
    alert("Cart saved successfully.");
}).error(function (data, status, request) {
    alert('There was a problem saving this cart. Please try again.');
});
```

Comment: What does your browser console say when the call goes out? Use Chrome's web inspector's network panel to inspect the request and response.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may be missing the csrf token:

html

```
<meta id="token" name="token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

js

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('content');
```

Comment: Thank you - that  was the error.  I forgot about that because I had my jquery properly set up with $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
        });  So the jquery worked.  However, that doesn't attach itself to the vue-resource request.

Comment: Is `csrf_token` Lavarel related?

Comment: yes, it is defined in laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

Answer (score 9):

Vue's author has stopped updating and maintaining vue-resource. He himself also suggested using axios, axios more easy to use and easy to maintain.
[axios introduction](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

If you just started learning Vue, here's an entry-level demo. Although it is only a small application, but it covers a lot of knowledge points (vue2.0 + vue-cli + vue-router + vuex + axios + mysql + express + pm2 + webpack), including front-end, back-end, database and other sites Some of the necessary elements, for me, learning great significance, would like to encourage each other!

[Github Demo](https://github.com/alloyteamzy/vue2_blog/)

Answer (score 4):

The code should be:

```
this.$http.post('/purchase/save-cart-items', {purchaseItems:purchaseItems})
    .success(function (data, status, request) {
        alert("Cart saved successfully.");
    })
    .error(function (data, status, request) {
        alert('There was a problem saving this cart. Please try again.');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that code isn't formatted correctly.

Comment: You're right, I edited my post with the correct code.

Answer (score 0):

The code should be:

```
 this.$http.post('purchase/save-cart-items', {purchaseItems:purchaseItems})
        .success(function (data, status, request) {
            alert("Cart saved successfully.");
        })
        .error(function (data, status, request) {
            alert('There was a problem saving this cart. Please try again.');
        });
```

or try with tymon/jwt-auth packages